# Docker save without docker pull

Tags: docker

I would like to save a docker image as a tar file. I can

```
docker pull my_repo/image:latest
docker save -o image.tar my_repo/image:latest
```

Is there a way to bypass the **docker pull**? What I would like to do is just

```
docker save -o image.tar my_repo/image:latest
```

When I try **docker save** alone I get:  Error response from daemon: reference does not exist

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to actually have the image locally before you can `docker save` it.  (Unlike `docker run` it won't pull it on its own.)

If you have the source to the image, it works equally well to

```
docker build -t my_repo/image:latest .
docker save -o image.tar my_repo/image:latest
```

If you don't then you need to `docker pull` it first, as you have in the question; there's no way around this.

Comment: The docker build command is going to build an image from a Dockerfile. I don't have the Dockerfile.

Comment: I edited my answer slightly to clarify.  You need the image locally in some form and the two ways to get it are `docker pull` and `docker build`.

Comment: This should be an added feature.  I should be able to save from a registry without having to download first.  Waste of space to have it on the system twice.  Seems like a hybrid of pull and save is needed for that.  Feature request anyone?